# is it possible to tell NSIS to setof files listed in a config file?

Tags: nsis

I have to download different files from a location on the network, http, but the file names versions I want to supply in a configuration file. is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read from files with the NSIS [ini instructions](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#readinistr), manual parsing with [FileRead](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#fileinst) or use one of the [helper macros](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#textfunc).

You can download files with the [INetC](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Inetc_plug-in) plugin...